# Floodlight tag on bigcommerce website

Tags: php, html, bigcommerce

My boss runs all her websites on the bigcommerce platform and i'm trying to implement a Google Floodlight tag for our adwords tracking. Due to the fact the site is essentially out of the box we don't have a dedicated web developer, so this has fallen on my desk.

Bigcommerce has two preset variables for use in conversion tags, which you can see below as order amount and order ID. I need to be able to track number of items, product name etc but bigcommerce are unwilling to give me any support on this.

Are any of you experienced with the bigcommerce system, or do you know any work arounds to implement these tags?

```
<iframe src="https://1706260.fls.doubleclick.net/activityi;src=1706260;type=clubc541;cat=clubc728;qty=1;cost=%%ORDER_AMOUNT%%;u3=[Number_of_Items];u4=[Promo_Code];u1=[Product_Name];u2=[Product_ID];ord=%%ORDER_ID%%?" width="1" height="1" frameborder="0"style="display:none"></iframe>
```

The website is www.club-cleo.com

Comment: Use WebDav and manually edit the template files. If you want it on all pages add it the a template file (like the header) that is used on all pages. Beware that if you update a theme these changes will be overwritten...

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever, I don't think you have read the question properly

Comment: The list of store wide variables are available @ https://developer.bigcommerce.com/themes/variables don't think product name is available, number of items in basket certainly is...

Comment: global variables do not work with floodlight conversion tags, it has to be an order variable, see my example

Comment: Could you do it using the web-api and webhooks to retrieve orders and products and then post them?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this guide Bigcommerce has. It's written specifically for Google Analytics, but all it does is remap conversion values they load on the order.html page into a new script. You could easily modify this script to pass the variables in as you need them :)
https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1195/